# Why does the old collision still interact with other simulated object?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

It's as the title says. I made some cheese react with my burger patty using the cloth simulation modifier. This works fine, but I wanted some tomatoes to fall on the cheese and eventually some lettuce and the top bun if I can get this to work! Unfortunately, the tomato bounces off the "air" instead of falling on the cheese. It took more than awhile for me to figure out that what the  tomato was bouncing off of WAS the cheese, but it's the collision for the cheese if it was perfectly still. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

The cheese is a rigid body (passive) with cloth modifier, every other object has passive rigid body collision except the tomato, which has active rigid body collision.

[Here's the video of the problem](https://youtu.be/CWTzF0JG-M8)

[image]

Comment: remove "Rigid Body" modifier from the cheese. That fixed it for me after i baked it.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!